# Return a string instead of field value when condition is met in MySQL

Tags: mysql

With my ongoing saga to try to do things directly in the database instead of using some php-logic, another question.

For instance: I've got a table: `m/ id | by | msg` an id, by who is this done and what is the message. The `by` field is an integer connected to another table which stores the name. Normally I would left join the two tables:

```
SELECT m.id, m.msg, user.name FROM m LEFT JOIN user ON m.by = u.id
```

With the resulting relation, e.g.:

```
1 | Hello World | Richard
2 | Foo Bar     | Some else
3 | Howdy       | Richard
```

I'm richard and have `user.id=4`

Is it possible to have the resulting relation to display `you` instead of `Richard` where the condition `user.id = (int)` is met?

Comment: Where is "you" defined ? ie how would you now that you = user.id 4

Comment: That's a variable which I get from php....

Comment: So you could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10639768/572939) and replace the `123` with your PHP variable and it will work

Comment: do it in php otherwise i think you need SP

Comment: @ManseUK: Thanks, I've updated my answer to use `4` (didn't see that in the original question).

Comment: @eggyal the `4` should be replaced with a PHP variable - as the userid wont always be `4` !!!

Comment: @ManseUK: Quite right, but I'll leave that detail out of my answer (unless the OP requests it) as otherwise I'll bog myself down in how to properly parameterise queries, which is not really what the question is asking!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, m.msg, IF(user.id = 4, 'you', user.name) AS name
FROM m LEFT JOIN user ON m.by = user.id
```

Comment: I've adjusted the query just a little bit, to make the user id variable: `IF(user.id = :by , 'you', user.name)` to be used by PDO. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.msg, 
(case when user.id = 4 then 'You'
 else user.name end) as username
FROM m LEFT JOIN user ON m.by = u.id
```